# Limit array to specific type - custom Texture Class C#?

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to create a custom texture class, and I want to be able to choose if I the texture is 8bit or float a.k.a I want to be able to set `_buffer` to be either `RGBFloat[]` or `RGBByte[]`  but I cant figure out how to do it with out making the whole class generic but if I do it generic it will be possible to set other object types other then just the ones that I want to limit it to. Maybe its possible to use inheritance or interface in some way, I don't know.

**Example C# Code:** *(the places with T are not correct, just placeholder)*

```
public struct RGBFloat
{
    public float R { get; }
    public float G { get; }
    public float B { get; }

    public RGBFloat(float r, float g, float b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}

public struct RGBByte
{
    public byte R { get; }
    public byte G { get; }
    public byte B { get; }

    public RGBByte(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}

public enum TextureFormat
{
    RGBFloat,
    RGBByte
}

public class Texture2D
{
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }
    private T[] _buffer; // want it to be able to be either RGBFloat[] or RGBByte[] but nothing else.

    public Texture2D(int width, int height, TextureFormat textureFormat)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        switch (textureFormat)
        {
            case TextureFormat.RGBFloat:
                _buffer = new RGBFloat[width * height];
                break;
            default:
                _buffer = new RGBByte[width * height];
                break;
        }
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[i]); }
        set { _buffer[i] = value; }
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[Width * y + x]); }
        set { _buffer[Width * y + x] = value; }
    }
}
```

**Example of a working generic class I have created that is similar to my TextureClass but this one is meant to be able to support any object type.**

```
public class Computebuffer<T>
{
    public int Count { get; }
    private T[] _buffer;

    public Computebuffer(int count)
    {
        Count = count;
        _buffer = new T[count];
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[i]); }
        set { _buffer[i] = value; }
    }

    public void Initialize(T value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            _buffer[i] = value;
        }
    }

    public void SetData(T[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            _buffer[i] = data[i];
        }
    }

    public void GetData(T[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = _buffer[i];
        }
    }


    public void Clear()
    {
        _buffer = new T[Count];
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** *(Updated version, almost working)*: 
**Issue:** With this code I am able to add a RGBFloat to a Texture2D and that doesn't make sense. *(see main program)*

```
public interface IRGBType { }

public struct RGBFloat : IRGBType
{
    public float R { get; }
    public float G { get; }
    public float B { get; }

    public RGBFloat(float r, float g, float b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}

public struct RGBByte : IRGBType
{
    public byte R { get; }
    public byte G { get; }
    public byte B { get; }

    public RGBByte(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}


public class Texture2D<T> where T : struct, IRGBType
{
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }
    private IRGBType[] _buffer;

    public Texture2D(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        _buffer = new IRGBType[width * height];
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(RGBByte))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Width * Height; i++)
            {
                _buffer[i] = new RGBByte(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Width * Height; i++)
            {
                _buffer[i] = new RGBFloat(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }

    }

    public IRGBType this[int i]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[i]); }
        set { _buffer[i] = value; }
    }

    public IRGBType this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[Width * y + x]); }
        set { _buffer[Width * y + x] = value; }
    }
}
```

**MainProgram:**

```
Texture2D<RGBFloat> texFloat = new Texture2D<RGBFloat>(64, 64);
Texture2D<RGBByte> texByte = new Texture2D<RGBByte>(64, 64);
texFloat[32, 32] = new RGBFloat(10, 50, 60);
texByte[32, 32] = new RGBFloat(0.9f, 0.24f, 0.5f); // this should not work I should not be able to add a RGBFloat to a RGBByte Texture2D
```

**EDIT 2:** *(Updated version v3)* still one issue, how would I Initialize `_buffer` array with an optional value, so new `Texture2D<RGBFloat>(64, 64)` should Initialize with `new RGBFloat(0,0,0)` and `Texture2D<RGBFloat>(64, 64, new RGBFloat(0.5f,0.6f,0.7f))` should Initialize with value provided:

```
public class Texture2D<T> where T : struct, IRGBType
{
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }
    private T[] _buffer;

    public Texture2D(int width, int height, T? initializeValue = null)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        _buffer = new T[width * height];
        Initialize(initializeValue);
    }

    private void Initialize(T? value)
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        T rgb;
        if (type == typeof(RGBFloat))
        {
            rgb = value ?? new RGBFloat(0, 0, 0); // Error: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'RGBFloat'
        }
        else
        {
            rgb = value ?? new RGBByte(0, 0, 0); // Error: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'RGBByte'
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < Width*Height; i++)
        {
            _buffer[i] = rgb;
        }
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[i]); }
        set { _buffer[i] = value; }
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[Width * y + x]); }
        set { _buffer[Width * y + x] = value; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:** The full final version that now works correctly:

```
public interface IRGBType { }

public struct RGBFloat : IRGBType
{
    public float R { get; }
    public float G { get; }
    public float B { get; }

    public RGBFloat(float r, float g, float b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}

public struct RGBByte : IRGBType
{
    public byte R { get; }
    public byte G { get; }
    public byte B { get; }

    public RGBByte(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}

public class Texture2D<T> where T : struct, IRGBType
{
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }
    private T[] _buffer;

    public Texture2D(int width, int height, T? initializeValue = null)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        _buffer = new T[width * height];
        if (initializeValue.HasValue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Width * Height; i++)
            {
                _buffer[i] = initializeValue.Value;
            }
        };
    }

    public T this[int i]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[i]); }
        set { _buffer[i] = value; }
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return (_buffer[Width * y + x]); }
        set { _buffer[Width * y + x] = value; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not just create a pair of derived classes that use the appropriate generic type parameter? You can make the constructor for the generic base class `protected internal`, to prevent code outside the assembly from subclassing the base class with some different (inappropriate) array type. There are, actually, lots of ways to approach this goal. Your question is very broad, without you providing some specific constraints and explanations of what you've tried and why the alternatives you've already tried don't work for you.

Comment: Don't declare the array as `IRGBType`, declare it as `T` inside `Texture2D<T>`. Same with indexers and `_buffer`. I updated my answer to reflect that; sorry, I figured it's implied with generic class.

Comment: @CoolBots yep  that fixed it. but I still have a bit of a problem Initializing `_buffer `array because I want to have an optional value, but can't figure out how to do it with a generic type. _(see EDIT 2)_

Comment: Remove your `Initialize` method - it's not necessary. `T` is already strongly typed, and is a `struct` (value type; copied on assignment) - just check if `initializeValue.HasValue`, and if true, loop through the array in the constructor, and assign `initializeValue.Value` to each array index. If no value is provided, each element in the array is already `default(T)` - in your case, exactly what your code is setting it to if no value is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an interface that your `RGBFloat` and `RGBByte` structs implement, and limit the generic type to that interface. The interface can just be a "marker", with nothing in it:

```cs
public interface IRGBType { }

public struct RGBFloat : IRGBType
{
    public float R { get; }
    public float G { get; }
    public float B { get; }

    public RGBFloat(float r, float g, float b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}

public struct RGBByte : IRGBType
{
    public byte R { get; }
    public byte G { get; }
    public byte B { get; }

    public RGBByte(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

You can then have your generic class only accept types that implement this interface:

```cs
public class Texture2D<T> where T: IRGBType
{
  ...
}
```

If you know that you'll always have this interface implemented by a `struct`, you can further restrict the generic:

```cs
public class Texture2D<T> where T: struct, IRGBType
{
  ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Make sure to use the generic `T` parameter everywhere in your class, not the interface. This is necessary to ensure type safety, otherwise your indexers can accept *any* `IRGBType`, which can be very problematic. Correct usage:

```cs
public class Texture2D<T> where T: struct, IRGBType
{
  private T[] _buffer;

  public Texture2D(int width, int height)
  {
      ...
      _buffer = new T[width * height];
      ...
  }

  public T this[int i]
  {
      get => _buffer[i];
      set => _buffer[i] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code based on your suggestion but I still have one issue with it, if I create a new byte Texture2D like this: `Texture2D<RGBByte> texByte = new Texture2D<RGBByte>(64, 64);` I should NOT be able to add a RGBFloat to it like this: `texByte[32, 32] = new RGBFloat(0.9f, 0.24f, 0.5f);` currently that is possible, got any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: See my comment on your post and my updated answer - you're using `IRGBType` interface inside your generic class - don't do that, declare everything as `T`

Comment: Must absolutely use T (with struct restriction) or it has same heap-explosion as other answer(s). Heap allocation is terrible for “pixels” due to n*m nature of domain.

Comment: Using T everywhere in the class also fulfills the original question as T is invariant.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using only one generic struct like this:

```
public struct RGB<T>
where T : struct,
          IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible,
          IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
  public T R { get; }
  public T G { get; }
  public T B { get; }
  public RGB(T r, T g, T b)
  {
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
  }
}

public class RGBComputeBuffer<T>
where T : struct,
          IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible,
          IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
  public int Count { get; private set; }
  private RGB<T>[] _buffer;

  public RGBComputeBuffer(int count)
  {
    _buffer = new RGB<T>[count];
    Count = count;
  }

  public RGB<T> this[int i]
  {
    get { return _buffer[i]; }
    set { if ( !_buffer[i].Equals(value) ) _buffer[i] = value; }
  }

  public void Initialize(RGB<T> value)
  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i++ )
      _buffer[i] = value;
  }

  public void SetData(RGB<T>[] data)
  {
    Array.Resize(ref _buffer, data.Length);
    Count = data.Length;
    for ( int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++ )
      _buffer[i] = data[i];
  }

  public void GetData(RGB<T>[] data)
  {
    Array.Resize(ref data, _buffer.Length);
    for ( int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++ )
      data[i] = _buffer[i];
  }

  public void Clear()
  {
    _buffer = new RGB<T>[Count];
  }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var bufferOfRGBByte = new RGBCompositeBuffer<byte>(100);
var bufferOfRGBFloat = new RGBCompositeBuffer<float>(100);
```

Comment: It might also be good to restrict T to a struct (covers all primitive numeric types).

Answer (score 1):

An interface would be your best bet. By having RGBFloat and RGBByte implement an interface then you can use that interface type in your array. It will also allow adding other RGB types later.

```
    public interface IRGB
    {

    }

    public struct RGBFloat : IRGB
    {
        public float R { get; }
        public float G { get; }
        public float B { get; }

        public RGBFloat(float r, float g, float b)
        {
            R = r;
            G = g;
            B = b;
        }
    }

    public struct RGBByte : IRGB
    {
        public byte R { get; }
        public byte G { get; }
        public byte B { get; }

        public RGBByte(byte r, byte g, byte b)
        {
            R = r;
            G = g;
            B = b;
        }
    }

    public enum TextureFormat
    {
        RGBFloat,
        RGBByte
    }

    public class Texture2D
    {
        public int Width { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        private IRGB[] _buffer; // want it to be able to be either RGBFloat[] or RGBByte[] but nothing else.

        public Texture2D(int width, int height, TextureFormat textureFormat)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            switch (textureFormat)
            {
                case TextureFormat.RGBFloat:
                    _buffer = new IRGB[width * height];
                    break;
                default:
                    _buffer = new IRGB[width * height];
                    break;
            }
        }

        public IRGB this[int i]
        {
            get { return (_buffer[i]); }
            set { _buffer[i] = value; }
        }

        public IRGB this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return (_buffer[Width * y + x]); }
            set { _buffer[Width * y + x] = value; }
        }
    }
```

If you want to access the R,G,B variables however you may need to add some kind of accessor methods/properties to the interface.

Comment: Marking the types in `Texture2D` without using the concrete classes, none of the fields in the structs will be accessible in calling code. Making `Texture2D` generic like the other answer suggests will be much more useful.

Comment: This code doesn't try to construct an interface. It constructs an array of the interface type.

Comment: in this example how would the how would the switch case work? `TextureFormat.RGBFloat` and `default` (RGBByte) is the same wouldn't the switch case be redundant?

Comment: @PatrikFröhler Yes you are correct, its no longer required as you can instantiate the array immediately in the constructor. I just added in the Interface changes.

Comment: This code will force struct-to-object-promotion, which is VERY INEFFICIENT for image handling. Don’t want a million heap-allocated objects for a 1MP image!